# Einstein Bot conversation limit

Tags: einstein-bots

I was going through help document for Einstein bot where I came across the below [statement](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_limitations.htm&type=5)

[image]

In other forums I have found related statements saying there are **25 free bot sessions per month for each chat** **license** in the Salesforce environment.

I have been exploring bots in my developer edition org wherein I must have initiated hundreds of sessions over the course of this month itself. Now that there are two chat licenses in my developer edition org the number of free conversations should be limited to 50.

Is my interpretation of the limitation correct and if so why have I been able to successfully launch so many sessions.